Random numbers generated are often too high for simulation?
I am working on a problem where I need to simulate when an entity remains "active in a system" as time passes by.The following is a simplified setting that describes my issue.
I have estimated probabilities of being active in the system. These probabilities look reasonable. For instance, the chance of being active in the system are 94.29% (or 0.9429 as used in model), 93.57%,92.77%, 91.88% for the first, second, third and fourth period respectively. Probabilities decrease as expected, with the chance of being active in the system after 10 years being 84.11%  (similarly, 60% for 20 years). With such high probabilities of remaining active, I would expect entities to remain active for a long period of time as is the case in empirical information.
Since I want to assess entities being active for the next 60 years, I generate 60 random numbers in R using the instruction random_numbers<-runif(60). Then the entity is active in a given year under two conditions: first, it had to be active in the previous year (no re-entry), and second the respective random number must be smaller than the probability of remaining active. For instance, an entity would be active in the third year only if 1) it was active in the second year, and 2) the third randomly generated number is smaller than 0.9277. I do find this methodology reasonable, and results seem to be as expected in a single simulation.
However, when I run 1000 such simulations, I notice that entities are not remaining active for as long as I would expect given the high probabilities I have computed. Indeed, average number of years active is just about 8, but the probability of being active after ten years is still super high (84.11% as mentioned previously). When I check the matrix of random numbers generated (which I have saved), I realize that indeed there are most often than not very high numbers (0.90+) in the first 10 positions. How is that possible? Doesn't that mean that high numbers are appearing much more often than expected? Is there something that I may be doing wrong?
I appreciate any help.
I have increased the number of simulations to 2000, 3000, and even 4000 (which takes a long time and memory often collapses), and I always get an average of about 8 years in the system.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You should show your code to make it more clear exactly what's going on. If you need help interpreting the results of the simulation or setting up the simulation, that's more of a statistical issue that would belong on [stats.se] rather than Stack Overflow. Perhaps your expectations are just incorrect. See how to create a reproducible example.

What 'decay' of 'active' is suggested in your empirical information, and welcome to Stackoverflow and code please.

Since you appear to be looking at survival times, why not generate survival times directly?  For example with desp or dweibull?  It's easy to apply cebnsoring in such a situation if necessary.  But I believe your question is far, far to vague to be sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Sorry, this is too long for just a comment.
You are mixing together two different things:
The probability of being active in a given year and
the probability of being active
given that it made it through the first year.
The absolute probability vs the conditional probability.
You wrote:
For instance, an entity would be active in the third year only if

it was active in the second year, and
the third randomly generated number is smaller than 0.9277.

Let's go back one step. Presumably,
an entity would be active in the second year only if

it was active in the first year, and
the second randomly generated number is smaller than 0.9357.

What is the probability of that happening?
Since the probability of being active in the first year is 0.9429
and the probability of the second condition is 0.9357, the
probability of meeting BOTH conditions is 0.9429*0.9357 = 0.8822715
The way that you are using it, the 0.9357 is the probability of
being active given that it made it through the first year.
Maybe that is what you wanted (1-0.9357) = 0.0643 of the entities active
at the end of year 1, become inactive in year two. That will lead to the above
result that only 0.8822715 will be active at the end of the second year.
If you truly want to have 93.57% still active at the end of the second year,
you must use different probabilities for dropping out.  You must solve

0.9429 * X = 0.9357
X = 0.992364


and make your second number be 0.992364.
So what did you mean?  Did you mean that the conditional probability or
the absolute probability?
